# How does image loading works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the image-loading construction in js:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    //do something
}
img.src = "path to image";
```

I'm curious way this works, that after assigning string to object some event is triggered. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: FYI, `new Image()` is equivalent to `document.createElement('img')`.

Comment: This is very useful for making it cache images to be loaded later, like those used by hidden elements (hidden by either rule - `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Image` is a special object (known in the spec as a *host object*) whose implementation is provided by the browser.  The constructor is actually returning a new [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement).

Internally, the `src` property has a setter function.  When you set the `src`, the browser begins fetching the image in the background.  (The exact mechanism by which this happens varies from browser to browser.)

When the request for the image completes *successfully*, the browser fires the `load` event.  (If unsuccessful, it will fire the `error` event.)

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a string to the `src` property of the `Image` object the browser sends a request for the image from the server specified in the URL that should be in that string.

When the response comes back from the server with a valid image, the `load` event is triggered, and the `onload` event handler is called.